# C - print from a pointer in the buffer

Tags: c

Working on a CS class - C course problem. Part of the problem is to create a function to print the specified length from a char buffer, given a char pointer to print from.

Signature of the function to be called in loop:

```
bool printLine(char cbuffer, char *ptr, int bufferFillLength)
```

where `cbuffer` is the pointer to the beginning of the buffer, `ptr` is the pointer to the start of the string to print. Variable `bufferFillLength` is the number of characters to print from the buffer starting at `ptr`.

The function should be called in loop until the end of the line is reached (i.e function returns false).

Here is my attempt but not working and looking for help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 300

bool printLine (char cbuffer, char *ptr, int printLength){
    char *bufferprinttext;
    
    strncpy (bufferprinttext, &cbuffer[ptr], printLength);
    printf("%s", bufferprinttext);
    if(bufferprinttext[strlen(bufferprinttext)-1] == '\n') {
       //end of line reasched - return false;
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char cbuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int printLength = 25;
    bool isItEndOfBuffer = false;
    int bufferCounter = 0;

    cbuffer = "Fusce dignissim facilisis ligula consectetur hendrerit. Vestibulum porttitor aliquam luctus. Nam pharetra lorem vel ornare condimentum. Praesent et nunc at libero vulputate convallis. Cras egestas nunc vitae eros vehicula hendrerit. Pellentesque in est et sapien dignissim molestie.";

    while(isItEndOfBuffer == false) {
        ++bufferCounter;
        
        isItEndOfBuffer = printLine(cbuffer, &cbuffer[printLength * bufferCounter], printLength);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: For booleans just test straight up with `if (!x)` instead of `if (x == false)`.

Comment: Hint: `strncpy` to an uninitialized pointer = bad times.

Comment: Are you sure you have the signature right? `cbuffer` is not a pointer in `PrintLine`. You should get a warning or error calling it because of the mismatch.. https://godbolt.org/z/78z8Kbec4 You also cannot assign a string to an array like that, you need something like `strcpy`.

Comment: Tip: Don't copy the string, just selectively print part of it with something like `fwrite`.

Comment: There's a whole heap of problems here that suggest you've skipped over a lot of C fundamentals, so it's worth checking you have a good reference before you start bashing out code like this and getting into trouble really fast. You can't just assign a pointer to a buffer, you need to `strncpy()` it. Tip: Use `char cbuffer[] = "..."` if you want a mutable buffer, or just `char* cbuffer = "..."` if you won't be modifying it.

Comment: It's also important to read function documentation *very carefully* as `strncpy()` has a behaviour you must be aware of: "If count is reached before the entire array src was copied, **the resulting character array is not null-terminated.**" As such, jamming that into `printf` is a great way to crash your program.

Comment: another tip: Use `fputs` when formatting is not needed and if you don't mind the new line character you can use `puts` to directly write to stdout. `fputs(bufferprinttext, stdout);`
Also `strncpy` doesn't allocate memory for you, you have to allocate memory before.

Comment: What is the `char cbuffer` parameter supposed to do?  On the face of it, you can use `bool printLine (char cbuffer, char *ptr, int printLength){ printf("%.*s", printLength, ptr); return true; }` — that is, the `printf()` formats have the necessary support.  Failing that, `bool printLine (char cbuffer, char *ptr, int printLength){ for (int i = 0; i < printLength && *ptr != '\0' ; i++) putchar(*ptr++); return true; }`.

Comment: If `cbuffer` is supposed to be the start of the buffer and `ptr` is a pointer in the middle, it looks like `cbuffer` is wholly unnecessary, unless you have to check there's no EOL (`'\n'`) or EOS (`'\0'`) before where `ptr` points.  The suggestions in my previous comment ignore `cbuffer` because it is not really needed.  If you've got to stop at end of line (EOL, aka `'\n'`) or end of string (EOS, aka '\0'), then the `printf()` solution in my previous comment is too simplistic and won't work properly.  It's easy to adapt the looping function to test for EOL as well as EOS.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler: I have update the code per your comment. The function prints now but truncated at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

`cbuffer` is not a pointer as you say but is passed by value, thus you are not holding it's original reference as you seem to want. Try with the signature
`bool printLine (char *cbuffer, char *ptr, int printLength);`

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan Leffler: I have update the code per your comment. The function prints now but truncated at the beginning. Couldn't figure out what I am missing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 300

bool printLine (char cbuffer, char *ptr, int printLength){ 
    for (int i = 0; i < printLength; i++) {
        putchar(*ptr++);
        
        if(*ptr == '\0') {
            //end of line reasched - return false;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int printLength = 25;
    bool isItEndOfBuffer = false;
    int bufferCounter = 0;

    char* cbuffer = "Fusce dignissim facilisis ligula consectetur hendrerit. Vestibulum porttitor aliquam luctus. Nam pharetra lorem vel ornare condimentum. Praesent et nunc at libero vulputate convallis. Cras egestas nunc vitae eros vehicula hendrerit. Pellentesque in est et sapien dignissim molestie.";
    //printf ("cbuffer - start ptr=%p \n", &cbuffer[0]);

    printf("Text to print:\n %s \n\n", cbuffer);
    
    printf("But text is truncated at the begining by printLength(i.e. 25): \n");
    //printf ("\nisItEndOfBuffer=%d \n", isItEndOfBuffer );
    while( !isItEndOfBuffer ) {
        ++bufferCounter;
        //printf ("ptr=%p \n", &cbuffer[printLength * bufferCounter]);
        isItEndOfBuffer = printLine(*cbuffer, &cbuffer[printLength * bufferCounter], printLength);
        //printf ("\nisItEndOfBuffer=%d \n", isItEndOfBuffer );
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Text to print:
Fusce dignissim facilisis ligula consectetur hendrerit. Vestibulum porttitor aliquam luctus. Nam pharetra lorem vel ornare condimentum. Praesent et nunc at libero vulputate convallis. Cras egestas nunc vitae eros vehicula hendrerit. Pellentesque in est et sapien dignissim molestie.

But text is truncated at the begining by printLength(i.e. 25):
ligula consectetur hendrerit. Vestibulum porttitor aliquam luctus. Nam pharetra lorem vel ornare condimentum. Praesent et nunc at libero vulputate convallis. Cras egestas nunc vitae eros vehicula hendrerit. Pellentesque in est et sapien dignissim molestie.
```